# Core data relations between objects

Tags: core-data, ios6

Please suggest about how to create relation in Core Data in the following situation: I created a user object which contained 2 relations pointing to the same object (address) but relation names are homeAddress and workAddress. But on Xcode5 it gives some warning that the inverse relation is not reciprocal.

JSON:

```
 {
    "user": {
        "user_id": "123123",
        "email": "user@email.com",
        "first_name": "Jean Luc",
        "last_name": "Picard",
    "home_address": {
        "street": "DowningStreet",
        "number": "11",
        "city": "London",
        "state": "GreaterLondon",
        "country": "UnitedKingdom",
        "zip": "SW1A2QAB",
        "name": "Homesweethome",
        "created_at": "1365526421456",
        "location": {
            "latitude": 3.1,
            "longitude": 3.2
        }
    },
    "work_address": {
        "street": "AmphitheatreParkway",
        "number": "1600",
        "city": "MountainView",
        "state": "California",
        "country": "UnitedStates",
        "zip": "94043",
        "name": "WorkHarder",
        "created_at": "1365526642123",
        "location": {
            "latitude": 3.1,
            "longitude": 3.2
        }
    }
  }
}
```

I want to avoid creating 2 separate address objects.

Comment: What do you mean by "avoid creating 2 separate `Address` objects? do you want to merge them into one? if not, you will create 2 `Address` objects and assign them to the same `User` object, but you need to create 2 inverse relationships on the `Address` object one as `workUser` and one for `homeUser`

Comment: I mean...I do not want to create HomeAddress and WorkAddress (2 entities) because they both have same fields. I was thinking if I could have only 1 Address entity but create 2 relations in User entity.

Comment: You can define two relationships (homeAddress and workAddress) from User to the same Address entity. You just have to define two separate inverse relationships.

Comment: I did exactly the same thing...on Xcode 4.3 no problem but if I open the project on Xcode 5...it shows warning. Wired.

Comment: BTW, do you have any suggestion on a good lib (other than RestKit) which allows JSON to CoreData parsing and saving. The data can be either fetched from server and saved locally or local updated data can be sent to server. If anything changes on server, local data should update (without old deleting or creating new entries)